# Tailwindcss: Syntax error: The `hover:rounded-xl` class does not exist

Tags: css, create-react-app, tailwind-css

Syntax error: The `hover:rounded-xl` class does not exist, but `hover:rotate-12` does. If you're sure that `hover:rounded-xl` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS

Answer (score 1):

For this, to work you need to enable JIT mode in your `tailwind.config.js` file

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...,
  mode: "jit",
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped my day. I'm using PostCSS7 with Tailwind 2.2. It could be fixed by updating those to latest version (PostCSS 8 and Tailwind 3). But I don't want to mess my whole project up for compatibility reason. Didn't know Just-In-Time mode was a thing.